# Can I SSH into a machine using expect and interact using a single bash line?

Tags: ssh, expect, login-script

I have a bunch of scripts that do stuff already and I would just like to add this functionality to them.

I want to take the following simple expect script and turn it into a bash shell command that I could place in a bash script or run from my command line.

```
spawn ssh $machine
expect {
   "~]" {
      send "/etc/loginscript.sh\r"
      interact
   } 
}
```

I haven't been able to find a way to do this without saving my expect script to a file and calling it from bash. This is not a valid solution, I need to be able to just call this command from the CMD on a read only system.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use expect's `-c` option:

```
expect -c "spawn ssh \"$machine\"; expect { \"~]\" {send \"/etc/loginscript.sh\r\"; interact}}"
```

Comment: In this case the single quotes make my variables unreadable. I was able to make not nice workaround for that but using the -c is still not doing what I want. It creates the ssh spawn and then nothing else happens and it times out.  I might just give up on this for now.